# Required for HTML inputs working

Tags: javascript, html, input, flask, required

I'm developing a Flask application and I have the required tag inside of some HTML inputs , however they appear to not be working.

The basis of the app is that based on a select option selection, a different  with a different set of inputs is shown while the others are hidden. The following is some of the code though I left out a good amount as there is a lot and I feel this is all that is relevant, but I may be wrong. Currently everything functions except the use of "required" for some of the HTML inputs. What may be causing this?

HTML

```
<form id="observations" method="post" action="/Page" onsubmit="SubForm()">
  <div class="form-group row">
  *Some other inputs up here*
    <div class="form-group row" id="facts1" style="display:none;">
      <div class="form-group row" >
        <label class="col-sm-5 col-lg-5 col-md-5 form-control-label">fact_a* </label>
        <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4">
          <input class="form-control" name="fact_a" type="number" step="any" value= {{ fact_a }} required>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
   <div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-sm-4 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-4 col-sm-offset-2 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-xs-offset-2" >
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-success btn-lg">
       </div>
     </div>
</form>
```

The associated Javascript is:

```
 <!--  Shows different fields depending on which Facts type is input-->
     $('#myselect').on('change',function(){
    if( $(this).val()==="facts1"){
    $("#facts1").show()
    }
    else{
    $("#facts1").hide()
    }
    if( $(this).val()==="facts2"){
    $("#facts2").show()
    }
    else{
    $("#facts2").hide()
    }

function SubForm(){
         var facts1 = document.getElementById('facts1');
         var facts2 = document.getElementById('facts2');

        if (facts1.style.display == 'none') {
           // Get the parent of the facts1 node, then use it to remove its child facts1
           facts1.parentNode.removeChild(facts1);
        }
        if (facts2.style.display == 'none') {
           // Get the parent of the facts2 node, then use it to remove its child facts2
           facts2.parentNode.removeChild(facts2);
        }
     }
```

The subForm function is used so that the other div in my HTML (not shown), facts2, if not shown is deleted so its inputs are not submitted to Flask and into a dictionary

Other relevant information: I have a second form on this page which also has an input with type="submit" that is used to submit an uploaded csv file so that the contents of the csv file are populated into my HTML inputs via jinga2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure you are in a browser that supports the required tag. Most do, but I've experienced some IDEs with web views that don't
2. This line:

`<input class="form-control" name="fact_a" type="number" step="any" value= {{ fact_a }} required>`

When rendered, needs the double quotes around the value, so it may need to look like:
`<input class="form-control" name="fact_a" type="number" step="any" value="{{ fact_a }}" required>`

Comment: 2. did it for me thanks! Do you know why it needs the "" around {{ fact_a }} ? Without it does it assume that required is somehow part of the value?

Comment: @MVS Yeah, so all of those things are attributes. Class, name, type, step, value, and so on. You need to tell the browser whats an attribute and whats the value of that attribute. You do this by putting an attribute, like value, followed by an "=" and finally the value in double quotes. Your page was rendering without the double quotes, so the bowser thought something like "Okay, this attribute is called value={{fact_a}}", instead of "this attribute is called value with a value of {{fact_a}".